# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path nested json

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

i have problem about calling object, i think the problem is because nested json i convert to gson with pojo, but i do not know what code i must change to solved the problem

i receive this when start the app

> E/MainActivity: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

can you help me to figure out what i must to change so the problem "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY" can solved?

this is my original json [json](https://api.banghasan.com/sholat/format/json/jadwal/kota/663/tanggal/2022-01-16)

this is my data class

```
data class JadwalItem(

@field:SerializedName("jadwal")
val jadwal: Jadwal? = null,

@field:SerializedName("query")
val query: Query? = null,

@field:SerializedName("status")
val status: String? = null
)

data class Data(

@field:SerializedName("imsak")
val imsak: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("isya")
val isya: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("dzuhur")
val dzuhur: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("dhuha")
val dhuha: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("subuh")
val subuh: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("terbit")
val terbit: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("ashar")
val ashar: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("tanggal")
val tanggal: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("maghrib")
val maghrib: String? = null
)

data class Jadwal(

@field:SerializedName("data")
val data: Data? = null,

@field:SerializedName("status")
val status: String? = null
)

data class Query(

@field:SerializedName("kota")
val kota: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("format")
val format: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("tanggal")
val tanggal: String? = null
)
```

this is my service

```
@GET("tanggal/{year}-{monthNumber}-{day}")
fun getPosts(
    @Path("year") year: String,
    @Path("monthNumber") monthNumber: String,
    @Path("day") day: String
): Call<Posts>
```

this is my posts.kt

```
class Posts : ArrayList<Data>()
```

and this is i call service in mainactivity

```
    val dateNow = Calendar.getInstance().time
    val day = DateFormat.format("dd", dateNow) as String // 20
    val monthNumber = DateFormat.format("MM", dateNow) as String // 06
    val year = DateFormat.format("yyyy", dateNow) as String // 2013

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.banghasan.com/sholat/format/json/jadwal/kota/663/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val service: Service = retrofit.create(Service::class.java)

service.getPosts(year,monthNumber,day).enqueue(object : Callback<Posts> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Posts>, response: Response<Posts>) {
            val body = response.body()
            actionBar?.title = "Latihan"
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Posts>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", t.message.toString())
        }
    })
```

Comment: The actual problem is that your JSON is an array (i.e. it starts with an `[`) but you are trying to parse it as an object.  That's what the error message is saying.  That means you are not parsing the "original json" ... but something else.

Comment: so what i must do to solved the problem? @StephenC

Comment: Start by figuring out why you are parsing the wrong JSON file.

Comment: that JSON file i got from open API

Comment: That's not the point.  The point is that >that< JSON is not what you are actually parsing.  Change your code (or something) to figure out what you are actually parsing.   Seriously, this standard debugging strategy: before you can fix a problem you need to understand it and what caused it.  I can't help you with that ... beyond what I have already told you ... because you haven't provided enough debugging information.  For a start ... where are you parsing it?  Where is the stacktrace?

Comment: sorry, i newbie in this stuff, i already add a few information above, what i need to add anything else to help figure out what the problem is? @StephenC

Answer (score 0):

The JSON response is an array of "Post" objects, right? When your "getPosts" method return "Posts" object, you are expecting a JSON that represents "Post" object, not an array of it.

Change your:

```
class Posts : ArrayList<Data>()
```

to

```
data class Posts (val status: String, val query: Query, val jadwal: Jadwal) //Don't forget to use @SerializedName
```

Here you are telling your code that you expect "Post" response from API and "Post" is nothing more than an array of "Data"

Create a new class

```
data class ListOfPost(val posts: List<Posts>)
```

and your getPosts method will return Call ListOfPost